# Emulator.exe not working properly

Tags: android-emulator

I downloaded Android SDK and using Eclipse for development. 
I am trying to run HelloAndroid program.
Everything goes fine till the installation of the application.

**[2011-02-20 23:34:31 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2011-02-20 23:34:58 - HelloAndroid] Success!
[2011-02-20 23:34:58 - HelloAndroid] Starting activity com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid on device emulator-5554
[2011-02-20 23:35:01 - HelloAndroid] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.helloandroid/.HelloAndroid }**

Above is, what is there in the console tab.
As soon as I take my pointer to the Menu button on the emulator or after say 2-3 min... I receive the below mentioned error from windows.

**emulator.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience.**

Measures taken to solve this problem :

1. I turned off my firewall and tried running it, but it in vain.
2. I closed the emulator and re started it from the Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager, but in vain. I also tried checking the

> wipe user data

checkbox in the Manager window, but in vain.

PS: Only once till now the application did run properly and showed me the Hello Android Message but that too crashed. After that, the application has never even worked. It shows the home window with date and time, and crashes before showing the above mentioned reasons for the crash.

Also, I use Windows xp SP 2.0 and Eclipse 3.6.1. I choose min-sdkVersoin as 10.

Thaks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Minimum API level=8 (that would be Android 2.2.)

Failing that. Note the Eclipse and JVM versions in the [system requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html). I would stick with Eclipse "Classic" (3.5) if you're just trying to get your feet wet. Ensure that your JVM version is compatible.

I have found that Google don't really make things "linear" when it comes to installing stuff sometimes. Failing that, uninstall the JVM, and follow my deployment instructions I have written [here](http://crossingthechasm.posterous.com/pages/lets-start). As this is exactly what I did and never had any probs. Hope this helps.. good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much :-D . Switching to Minimum API Level = 8 - Android 2.2 did the trick. But I would like to know why didn't it work with 2.3 ? Thank you. :-)

Comment: Gosh! Knowing why it crashed on 2.3 would be hard to say. Too many variables to isolate unless there is a stack dump that would give us clues. Can you please mark my answer as correct if you're satisfied.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a new AVD (Android Virtual Device) from the SDK manager (without loading any apps)? Does it crash too? If it does, then you might think reinstalling SDK again cause somethin aint right.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. :-). Yes I tried that too. But switching to 2.2 did the trick. :-).